# Getting entity by list of ids in Appengine-Java

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have an appengine backend for an android app.

In this I want to retrieve a number of entities based on their 'id'

I've tried using a `WHERE IN` query for this as follows.

```
"select from MyEntity as MyEntity where id IN ('4538783999459328')"
```

The datastore contains a `MyEntity` with key that contains id as `4538783999459328`.
But the result set is blank. I have tried using other field names of the entity and it works, but am not able to filter with the id.

Is there any other way of doing this?

I'm using Appengine JAVA.

I don't want to use `EntityManager.find()` because I want to look up more than one id.

Comment: BTW, do you know that `IN` uses multiple queries behind the scenes (per doc), it just few findById queries?

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1. you have to use `__key__` instead of `id` in queries
2. there is a special Data type for Entity id - `Key('EntityName', ID)`

So, your query should look like this:

```
select * from MyEntity where __key__ in (Key('MyEntity', 4538783999459328))
```

Also, take a look at GQL doc: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/gqlreference

Answer (score 0):

All the frameworks that implements datastore have a choice of get entities by a list of IDs (Key), or how the above post with GQL is the same.